# Unable to install tensorflow==2.0.0beta1: wrapt conflict

Tags: macos, tensorflow

I want to install tensorflow2.0.0 but I can't even install tensroflow1.14.0.

I am using macbook pro. I kept running into problems that some packets version are not compatible. I then tried to uninstall certain packets then reinstall them but it didn't work.

Error message:

```
ERROR: thinc 6.12.1 has requirement msgpack<0.6.0,>=0.5.6, but you'll have msgpack 0.6.1 which is incompatible.
ERROR: thinc 6.12.1 has requirement wrapt<1.11.0,>=1.10.0, but you'll have wrapt 1.11.2 which is incompatible.
Installing collected packages: wrapt, tensorflow
  Found existing installation: wrapt 1.10.10
ERROR: Cannot uninstall 'wrapt'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.
```

Answer (score 0):

Execute the below command:

```
pip install wrapt==1.10.0 --ignore-installed
```